# Are Chrome tab IDs unique between Incognito and regular tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Google Chrome extension and I'm curious if I can rely on [tab IDs](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:guBpS1gxZcEJ:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) to be unique between all open "regular" and Incognito tabs on the same physical computer (same user account)?